# Merging multiple dataframes with applying different operation on each column

Tags: python, pandas

I have several daily CSV files with structure similar to this:

```
| resource | start_date | end_date   | total_usage | usage_per_hour | last_read  |
|----------|------------|------------|-------------|----------------|------------|
| s3       | 2023-01-01 | 2023-01-01 | 22333       | 930,54         | 2023-01-01 |
| s3       | 2023-01-02 | 2023-01-02 | 11233       | 468,04         | 2023-01-01 |
| s3       | 2023-01-03 | 2023-01-03 | 6356        | 264,83         | 2023-01-03 |
| s3       | 2023-01-04 | 2023-01-04 | 757547      | 31564,46       | 2023-01-03 |
| ec2      | 2023-01-01 | 2023-01-01 | 222         | 9,25           | 2022-12-31 |
| s3       | 2023-01-05 | 2023-01-05 | 8765        | 365,21         | 2023-01-05 |
| rds      | 2023-01-01 | 2023-01-01 | 111         | 4,63           | 2023-01-01 |
| rds      | 2023-01-02 | 2023-01-02 | 7576        | 315,67         | 2023-01-02 |
| rds      | 2023-01-03 | 2023-01-03 | 444         | 18,5           | 2023-01-02 |
| ec2      | 2023-01-02 | 2023-01-02 | 6664        | 277,67         | 2023-01-02 |
| ec2      | 2023-01-03 | 2023-01-03 | 4543        | 189,29         | 2023-01-02 |
```

I want to merge/concatenate them using pandas based on resource, but for each column I want to apply a different operation, for example:

- start_date and end_date should be set for the first day and last_day of the given period
- total_usage should be a sum of all daily usages for the given period
- usage_per_hour should be total_usage divided by all hours in the given period
- last_read should be the latest date from all csv files

I'm new in pandas world. How should I approach such a data manipulation?

Sample output:

```
| resource | start_date | end_date   | total_usage | usage_per_hour | last_read  |
|----------|------------|------------|-------------|----------------|------------|
| s3       | 2023-01-01 | 2023-01-05 | 806234      | 6718,62        | 2023-01-05 |
| ec2      | 2023-01-01 | 2023-01-03 | 11429       | 158,74         | 2023-01-02 |
| rds      | 2023-01-01 | 2023-01-03 | 8131        | 112,94         | 2023-01-02 |
```

Comment: Could you provide some sample data?

Comment: @Forin can you provide some sample data of what the output should look like?